# Billing details in PayPal express

Tags: cartthrob

I have filled in my checkout with the following details, note I have left Shipping Address 2 blank:

```
Billing
First Name: “Billing Name 1“
Last Name: “Billing Name 2“
Address 1: “Billing Address 1“
Address 2: “Billing Address 2“
City: “Billing City“
Post Code: “Billing Post Code“

Shipping
First Name: “Shipping Name 1”
Last Name: “Shipping Name 2”
Address 1: “Shipping Address 1”
City: “Shipping City”
Post Code: “Shipping Post Code”
```

I then submitted this to Paypal Express and choose to pay via CC within PayPal. The fields are populated thus:

```
Billing Information
First Name: Shipping
Last Name: 2
Address Line 1: Shipping Address 1
Address Line 2: Billing Address 2
Town: Shipping City
Postcode: Shipping Postcode

Postal Address
Same as billing address: checked
```

I understood that my billing details should have been used..

I read in the gateway instructions ”PayPal only displays shipping addresses on their payment capture page. If a shipping address is captured on your site, it will be sent to PayPal. If a shipping address is not captured on your site, the billing address will be assumed to be the shipping address and will be sent to PayPal instead.”

So I have submitted the billing info but it is still taking the shipping info.. except for the Shipping Address 2 field which I left blank. Also the first and last name are being cut down.

Is this working as it is meant to do or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is working as it is meant to although I do find it very strange. I have just come up against this problem myself today.

The CartThrob Paypal Express plugin checks to see if there is a shipping address, and if there is then it will transmit that to PayPal instead of the billing address.

Having said all this I don't really understand the logic behind this - I would prefer just the billing details to be sent to PayPal and I am considering re-writing the plugin myself.

PS: It also limits the first and last name to 31 characters which, I suspect, is why yours is getting cut off.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I am also using the example cart.js file in my checkout. I have just noticed that the copy billing info to shipping function copies everything apart from the country so this may also be adding to my problems.

Comment: I haven't looked at cart.js but from what you say it is doing the same thing as the PHP in the PayPal plugin. Just for info, I ended up re-writing the PHP plugin and removed the lines which copied the shipping address over to the billing address. A bit of a hack but works.